# Select value is not inserting into database

Tags: php, mysqli

I have admins who insert entries into database, other values are properly inserting into database but select option value is not inserting. Firstly admin loged in and his session start after that he add new entries to database. 
Please help.

My html form is

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form">

    <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
        <label for="SubjectMaterialTitle">Subject Material Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="sub_title" placeholder="Subject Material Title" class="form-control" required>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
        <label for="Downloadurllink">Download url link</label>
        <input type="text" name="sub_url" placeholder="Download url link" class="form-control" required>
    </div>                                      

    <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
        <input type="file" name="sub_file" id="exampleInputFile" required>
        <p class="help-block">Upload Image/File upto 2MB size only</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
        <label for="WritenBy">Writen By</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="writen_by">
            <?php if(isset($_SESSION['admin_email'])){ 
                        echo '<option value='. $_SESSION['admin_username'] .'>'. $_SESSION['admin_username'] .'</option> '; 
                  }
            ?>
        </select>
    </div>

</form>
```

PHP code is

```
<?php

include("includes/config.php");
global $con;
    if(isset($_POST['add_submat'])){

        //getting the text data from the fields
        $sub_title = $_POST['sub_title'];
        $sub_url = $_POST['sub_url'];
        $writen_by = $_POST['writen_by'];

        //getting image from the fields
        $sub_file = $_FILES['sub_file']['name'];
        $sub_file_tmp = $_FILES['sub_file']['tmp_name'];

        move_uploaded_file($sub_file_tmp,"sub-material-files/$sub_file");

        //insert data into table
        $insert_submat = "insert into m_study_material (sm_title,sm_downloadurl,sm_image,created_by) values ('$sub_title','$sub_url','$sub_file','$writen_by')";

        echo $insert_submat;

        $run_submat = mysqli_query($con, $insert_submat);

        //error_reporting(E_ERROR);

        if($run_submat){
            echo "<script>alert('Inserted Successfully.')</script>";
        } else{
            echo "Not inserted";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Please upload the database structure too. Or try copying the result of `echo $insert_submat` and pasting it into your DBMS Insert Query executor then post an image of the result here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add quotes arround value, thats why values is being post properly.

```
  <?php 
  if(isset($_SESSION['admin_email'])){ 
      echo '<option value="'. $_SESSION['admin_username'] .'">'. $_SESSION['admin_username'] .'</option> '; 
  } 
  ?>
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try" this?

Comment: @Rishi thanks... your answer is working for me for adding products.. .. but when i use same for edit function it's not working

Answer (score 0):

First fix

```
<div class="col-md-4 form-group">
    <label for="WritenBy">Writen By</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="writen_by">
        <?php if(isset($_SESSION['admin_email'])): ?>
            <option>
                <?= $_SESSION['admin_username']; ?>
            </option>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Second you should consider cleaning user input before inserting because your code is currently widely open to Injection attack.
[See more about SQL Injection in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

For example you could utilize helper function such as

```
function cleanInput($input)
{
    $search = array(
        '@<script[^>]*?>.*?</script>@si',   // Strip out javascript
        '@<[\/\!]*?[^<>]*?>@si',            // Strip out HTML tags
        '@<style[^>]*?>.*?</style>@siU',    // Strip style tags properly
        '@<![\s\S]*?--[ \t\n\r]*>@'         // Strip multi-line comments
    );
    $output = preg_replace($search, '', $input);
    return $output;
}
function prepare($input)
{
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        $input = stripslashes($input);
    }
    $input  = cleanInput($input);
    return mysql_real_escape_string($input);
}
```

This way you could do this before any sql query

```
$sub_title = prepare($_POST['sub_title']);
$sub_url = prepare($_POST['sub_url']);
$writen_by = prepare($_POST['writen_by']);
```

Comment: Yikes! That is a lot of unnecessary regex! The OP should use prepared statements.

Comment: Mr Jay Blanchard. For all we know his entire project has been built using this method. I for one have not used it for over two years so it's better we help protect his system while it's master grows at his own pace . @shekharjadhav there was a variable dollar operator before the return in prepare() function. that's why the code didn't work